# Logical operators with class/objects in C++

Tags: c++

Completely new to C++. Trying to understand classes and objects, so far I get the gist of it, as it's nothing too complicated for the very basics. However, this code I have wrote is not working as intended. It works somewhat, however it asks for user input twice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class FooFoo {
public :

string GetName() {
    cin >> name;
    return name;
}

private:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
FooFoo object;
if (object.GetName() == "John" || object.GetName() == "Chris")
{
    cout << "Yes";

}
else {
    cout << "No";
}

}
```

If I input "John", it will return yes right away. However, when I input anything else, it will prompt me to enter something again, and then the if/else acts accordingly to whatever I inputted.

Comment: And if you input anything else, your code will call `object.getName()` a second time. Pop quiz for you: what does `object.getName()` does?

Comment: I bet if you type in `John` it'll only print it once... food for thought

Comment: Maybe an article about [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and impure functions will be interesting for you.

Comment: It's almost like when it calls it a second time... it does cin again! Thanks guys, I feel kind of stupid now thinking about how obvious it was. So I would imagine in the future, even if its something simple as "2+2" best practice is to assign the object to a local variable?

Comment: What happened to _Ringo_, _George_ and _Paul_?

Answer (score 3):

You call `object.GetName()` twice which causes the input to be asked for twice.  Store the result of this function to a variable and use that in the if statement.  The || statement is short-circuited if the first expression is true.  This leads to the second call not being executed if the first is true.

Answer (score 2):

That is because GetName() is asking for input every time,

So the first time it is asking for x, if x isnt john it goes to the next test, which then gets input and tests that against x = chris.

try changing it to this:

```
int main()
{
FooFoo object;
string test = object.GetName()
if (test == "John" || test == "Chris")
{
    cout << "Yes";

}
else {
    cout << "No";
}

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Good catch, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Your current if statement effectively evaluates to:

```
if (object.GetName() == "John")
  cout << "Yes";
else if (object.GetName() == "Chris")
  cout << "Yes";
else
  cout << "No";
```

Try entering `Chris` followed by `John` and you should get `No`.

Just call `getName()` before the if statement, store the value in a local variable, then test that instead:

```
string name = object.GetName();
if (name == "John" || name == "Chris")
  cout << "Yes";
else
  cout << "No;
```